# Kotlin - Encoding Raw PCM data to ACC encoded using Media Codec and Muxer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediacodec, android-audiorecord, mediamuxer

Hi guys so I'm trying to encode the pcm audio received from android audiorecorder into aac encoding using Media Codec (The reason is I need both the raw pcm data but I also want to save it into a m4a file). I've not been able to get this to work yet and maybe need a new pair of eyes. The audio file I'm left with seems corrupted as it contains data but I can't play the audio:

Thoughts:

1. Maybe the audio recorder init values are not the same as the encoder?

Disclaimer:

1. I don't really have android or kotlin experience, please excuse this mess.

Recording code:

```kotlin
    private val audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
    private val recorderSampleRate = 44100
    private val recorderChannels = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
    private val recorderAudioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    private val samplesPerFrame = 2048
    private val bufferSizeRecording = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
        recorderSampleRate,
        recorderChannels,
        recorderAudioEncoding
    )
    private var audioRecord: AudioRecord? = null
    private var audioEncoder: AudioEncoder? = null
    val audioDataChannel = AudioChannel<ByteArray>()


    private fun initAudioRecorder() {
        val desiredBufferDurationMs = 50
        var bufferSize = (recorderSampleRate * desiredBufferDurationMs / 1000) * 2

        if (bufferSize < bufferSizeRecording) {
            bufferSize = ((bufferSizeRecording / samplesPerFrame) + 1) * samplesPerFrame * 2
        }

        audioRecord = AudioRecord(
            audioSource,
            recorderSampleRate,
            recorderChannels,
            recorderAudioEncoding,
            bufferSize
        )

        if (audioRecord?.state != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            Log.d(WSTAG, "Audio Record can't initialize!")
            return
        }

        audioRecord?.startRecording()
    }


    // Initialize the AudioEncoder
    private fun initializeAudioEncoder(outputFilePath: String) {
        audioEncoder = AudioEncoder(
            sampleRate = recorderSampleRate,
            samplesPerFrame = samplesPerFrame,
            outputFilePath = outputFilePath,
            audioDataChannel = audioDataChannel, // Pass the channel here
            encodingCompleteCallback = {
                // This callback will be called when encoding is complete
                // You can perform any post-processing or cleanup here
            }
        )
        audioEncoder?.startEncoding()
    }

    private fun record() {
        recordingJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val outputFilePath = reactApplicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath + "/output.m4a"
            initializeAudioEncoder(outputFilePath)
            val desiredBufferDurationMs = 50
            var bufferSize = (recorderSampleRate * desiredBufferDurationMs / 1000) * 2

            if (bufferSize < bufferSizeRecording) {
                bufferSize = ((bufferSizeRecording / samplesPerFrame) + 1) * samplesPerFrame * 2
            }

            val buf = ByteArray(bufferSize)

            try {
                while (isActive) {
                    val bytesRead = audioRecord?.read(buf, 0, buf.size) ?: break
                    if (bytesRead == -1) break
                    socket?.send(buf.toByteString(0, bytesRead))
                    //Send the ByteArray to the AudioDataCHannel
                    audioDataChannel.send(buf.copyOf(bytesRead))
                    //val pcmData = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf, 0, bytesRead)
                    //audioDataChannel.send(pcmData)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e)
                Log.d("Hello", "Error: ${e.message}")
                stop()
            }
        }
    }
```

Encoder Code:

```kotlin
package com.deepgram.Audio

import android.media.MediaCodec
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo
import android.media.MediaFormat
import android.media.MediaMuxer
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel

class AudioEncoder(
    private val sampleRate: Int,
    private val samplesPerFrame: Int,
    private val outputFilePath: String,
    private val audioDataChannel: Channel<ByteArray>,
    private val encodingCompleteCallback: (() -> Unit)?
) {
    private val MIME_TYPE = "audio/mp4a-latm"
    private val CHANNEL_COUNT = 1
    private val BIT_RATE = 64000
    private val AAC_PROFILE = MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC

    private var audioEncoder: MediaCodec? = null
    private var muxer: MediaMuxer? = null
    private var presentationTimeUs: Long = 0
    private var encodingJob: Job? = null
    private var trackIndex: Int = -1
    private var isEncoding = false

    fun startEncoding() {
        isEncoding = true
        initializeEncoderAndMuxer()
        startEncodingJob()
    }

    fun stopEncoding() {
        isEncoding = false
        encodingJob?.cancel()
    }

    private fun initializeEncoderAndMuxer() {
        deleteFileIfExists(outputFilePath)
        val f = File(outputFilePath)
        f.createNewFile()

        val format = MediaFormat()
        format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, MIME_TYPE)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, CHANNEL_COUNT)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, sampleRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, AAC_PROFILE)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 16384)

        audioEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE)
        audioEncoder?.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        audioEncoder?.start()

        muxer = MediaMuxer(f.absolutePath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
        val currentMuxer = muxer
        val currentAudioEncoder = audioEncoder

        if (currentMuxer != null && currentAudioEncoder != null) {
            trackIndex = currentMuxer.addTrack(currentAudioEncoder.outputFormat)
            currentMuxer.start()
        } else {
            // Handle the case where muxer is null
            trackIndex = -1
        }
    }

    private fun startEncodingJob() {
        encodingJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val outputFile = File(outputFilePath)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            try {
                while (isActive) {
                    val pcmData: ByteArray? = audioDataChannel.receive()
                    pcmData?.let {
                        encodeAudio(pcmData)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                outputStream.close()
                releaseEncoderAndMuxer()
                encodingCompleteCallback?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun encodeAudio(pcmData: ByteArray) {
        if (!isEncoding) return
        val inputBufferId = audioEncoder?.dequeueInputBuffer(-1)
        if (inputBufferId != null && inputBufferId >= 0) {
            val inputBuffer = audioEncoder?.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId)
            inputBuffer?.clear()
            inputBuffer?.put(pcmData)

            val presentationTime = calculatePresentationTimestamp()

            audioEncoder?.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, pcmData.size, presentationTime, 0)
        }

        val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
        var outputBufferId = audioEncoder?.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0)
        while (outputBufferId != null && outputBufferId >= 0) {
            val outputBuffer = audioEncoder?.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId)
            outputBuffer?.position(bufferInfo.offset)
            outputBuffer?.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size)

            muxer?.writeSampleData(trackIndex, outputBuffer!!, bufferInfo)
            audioEncoder?.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false)
            outputBufferId = audioEncoder?.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0)
        }
    }

    private fun calculatePresentationTimestamp(): Long {
        val frameDurationUs = (1_000_000L * samplesPerFrame) / sampleRate
        presentationTimeUs += frameDurationUs
        return presentationTimeUs
    }

    private fun releaseEncoderAndMuxer() {
        audioEncoder?.stop()
        audioEncoder?.release()
        muxer?.stop()
        muxer?.release()
    }

    private fun deleteFileIfExists(filePath: String) {
        val file = File(filePath)
        if (file.exists()) {
            val deleted = file.delete()
            if (deleted) {
                Log.d("AudioEncoder", "Deleted existing file at: $filePath")
            } else {
                Log.d("AudioEncoder", "Failed to delete existing file at: $filePath")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some logs:

```bash
2023-09-04 20:12:25.697  8368-12742 MediaCodec              com.deepgramexample                  I  Codec shutdown complete
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  I  Normal stop process
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Audio track stopping. Stop source
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Audio track source stopping
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Audio track source stopped
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12749 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  I  Received total/0-length (608/0) buffers and encoded 607 frames. - Audio
2023-09-04 20:12:25.701  8368-12749 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  I  Audio track drift time: 0 us
2023-09-04 20:12:25.702  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Audio track stopped. Stop source
2023-09-04 20:12:25.702  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Stopping writer thread
2023-09-04 20:12:25.702  8368-12748 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  0 chunks are written in the last batch
2023-09-04 20:12:25.702  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Writer thread stopped
2023-09-04 20:12:25.703  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  I  Ajust the moov start time from 46439 us -> 46439 us
2023-09-04 20:12:25.705  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  I  The mp4 file will not be streamable.
2023-09-04 20:12:25.705  8368-12740 MPEG4Writer             com.deepgramexample                  D  Audio track stopping. Stop source
2023-09-04 20:12:25.705  8368-12740 Hello                   com.deepgramexample                  D  Encoding Complete
```

I tried all of the code above, the end result was a corrupted file. I wanted to get a m4a file that I could play after I stop the audio recorder.

I could not find any other way of encoding live pcm data than using android media codec

Answer (score 0):

After a quick glance over your code I can see a few possible issues:

1. Don't forget to specify the [encoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#encoding) of the data when you configure the encoder.

   `format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PCM_ENCODING, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)`
2. If you call `currentAudioEncoder.outputFormat` immediately after configuring the codec you will get an incomplete format (as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#getOutputFormat())).
   You are supposed to do it either after you receive an `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` signal or after receiving the first output buffer.

   See an asynchronous mode [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#asynchronous-processing-using-buffers).

   See a synchronous mode [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#synchronous-processing-using-buffers).
3. Consider using `ByteBuffer` / `ShortBuffer` instead of `ByteArray` when working with raw data, in order to prevent bugs related to sample size and byte order.

   Another [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#raw-audio-buffers).